# HTML 5 History - Open/reload subpage

Tags: html, pushstate, html5-history

I build a website based on one html file. I based the routing on HTML 5 API History. I made the addresses of the subpage with help from history.pushState and everything is ok, eg www.mypage.com/about.

The problem is in this when I try to refresh the subpage or how I will go directly to the address www.mypage.com/about. You can have an idea to call the function after going to www.mypage.com/about.

I tried to do something like that, but I get a 404 error

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf ("about")> -1) {
     someAction (0);
}
```

However, if I added in the url address "?" or "#":
www.mypage.com/?about

Then this condition will be fulfilled and the function will be called.

Comment: I solved the problem with htaccess redirect: `Redirect 301 /about /?about`

Answer (score 0):

The point of the HTML5 History API is to *avoid* refreshing the browser. If refreshing the browser is what you *want* to do, then just call [`window.location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload):

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf ("about") >= 0) {
    window.location.reload();
}
```